# Difference between variable & parameter

Tags: calculus

Just started calculus 3, and I'm doing vector functions. What I don't understand is how a parameter function is any different from a standard $y(x) = 5x$ function, $x$ is the parameter in this function right?

If we could graph in $4$ dimensions, then wouldn't we be able to have $t$ as an axis for the parametric equations?

Is it just so simple that we use "parameter" instead of "variable" just cause we can't graph in $4$ dimensions, in which saying that it's a parameter rather then a variable separates it from the $x,y,z$ terms?

Comment: It is certainly not common to call some variables "parameters" just to lower the number of actual variables down to $3$. Calling it a "parameter" may imply that its value is chosen and then left fixed for the subsequent calculation. It could be also that the study is about functions of variables that are not independent (e.g. functions on a sphere), where the idea is to "parameterise" the variables - i.e. write them as functions of a smaller number of "parameters". Would you be able to provide some more context? - for example, a citation, a chapter from a book etc. which has left you puzzled?

Comment: @StinkingBishop https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/VectorFunctions.aspx here,

Comment: At the site you link to the word "parameter" is never used!   It does talk about "parametric equations" but not "parameters".  In any case, as used here, there is no difference between "variables" and "parameters".  In the "parametric equations" , x= f(t), y= g(t), it really makes no difference whether you call "t" a "parameter" or a "variable"- they are interchangeable.   If you really want to call attention to the fact that you can graph x and y on a coordinate system but not t, then you might call x and y "variables" and t a "parameter" but that is a "cosmetic" difference, not a real one.

Comment: The Wikipedia article [parametric equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) may answer your question.

Comment: some similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/609470, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2113138, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1290373, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193146

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

- We call "parameter(s)" the variable(s) of a given parameterization, where a "parameterization" of a given set $S$ means a function $f$ such that $Im(f)=S$. Thus, every parameter is a variable of a certain function.
- Every function is a parameterization (of its image). Therefore, every variable is also a parameter (of a certain parameterization).

The basic ideia is that when we talk about parameterization and parameter we are not interested in the function itself, but in the set that the function describes (i.e., the set parameterized by the function).

For example:

- $f:[-1,1]\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by $f(t)=(t,\sqrt{1-t^2})$ is a vector function of a single variable $t$.
- $g:[0,\pi]\to\mathbb R^2$ defined by $g(s)=(\cos(s),\sin(s))$ is a vector function of a single variable $s$.

We have $f\neq g$ (e.g., the domains are different). However, $Im(f)=Im(g)$, that is, $f$ and $g$ are different parameterizations of the same curve (semicircle, graph of the real valued function $y(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$). If you are interested in this particular curve, then you can choose the most convenient parameterization. Let us say that our parameterization is intended to describe the motion of a particle on this semicircle from the left to the right in function of time. Then:

- $f$ does not work because time should be positive.
- $g$ does not work because its motion goes from the right to the left.

We can fix it by changing the parameter $s$ of $g$ to $\pi-s$. The result is the different parameterization
$$h(s)=(\cos(\pi-s),\sin(\pi-s)),\quad s\in[0,\pi]$$
of the same curve, which goes from the left to the right with a positive parameter and thus suitable for our purposes.